# Handling infinite combos

Tags: game-design, architecture

I'm working on a game where entities can be affected by 'statuses' that can have an effect in response to any entity event (lost_life, turn_began...).

I'm searching for good ways of handling this kind of combo, where an entity have both statuses:
"On taking damage, heal 1"
"On healing, take 1 damage"

Until now, ways i thinked of include:

- Only allow automatic responses to direct actions (So a status won't trigger another):
  *Not acceptable as it limit too much the game design.*
- Pay attention while game-designing to not have circular interactions:
  *Not acceptable as I want an open modding interface.*
- Detect when a loop occurs programmatically:
  *Seems impossible as the loop can theorically be infinitely large.*
- Having a maximum amount of nested resolving statuses:
  *Actually my best guess.*

I searched informations about that online, but couldn't find more relevant information than the rules of physical card games as Magic or Yu-Gi-Oh. These could be useful, but I didn't found anything about their implementation in the related videogames.

Do you know any technique to handle this kind of behavior ?
Or any resource on the subject ?

Thanks.

Edit:
I should have mentionned that my game is turn based, and statuses are called sequentially, hence all happening in the same frame.

Comment: I think you should be able to detect loops, they won't be infinite long. The important part is that if you have multiple effects happening at the same time, that they will always happen in the fixed order and not one turn in one order and the next turn in a different order

Comment: @Alikae At least in Magic, there are rules to handle them but they require interpretation by a player that a loop is "infinite". In Arena and presumably the other online Magic simulators, you just get stuck in an infinite loop unless the game ends somehow (e.g., someone dies during the infinite)

Comment: #2 is still a good way to handle it. Try making your "statuses" more specific. For example: "Whenever taking damage from another player or NPC, heal 1". That way the rule is clear that it will not trigger the other status that applies 1 damage. What you have already should be written as: "Whenever taking damage from any source, heal 1". Which then does directly permit the other effect to trigger. I think if you provide this level of control to the modding interface it will help the modders design in a way that avoids infinite loops.

Comment: Also is your game turn-based or real-time? What about making a status have a flag to indicate if it has been processed already in the current turn or frame? If the flag is set then skip it. At the beginning of the turn or frame reset all of the flags.

Comment: [We have some past Q&A about dealing with infinitely re-triggering effects](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/168089/39518).

Comment: @Zibelas The loop can actually be infinintely long, or it can be a non-looping infinite chain of action, as random could be involoved in some statuses (then having something that 'mess' the loop detection, while not necessarily messing with the loop itself).

Comment: @Romen I feel like whatever attention i give to it, the more statuses will exist, the less it will be possible to have a cohesive design. Furthermore, I don't want to forbid effects like 'When you receive a stack of statusX, get a stack of statusY'.

My game is turn based. The flag idea would mean an effect cannot be triggered twice in the same 'chain', and I don't want that too.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanx, it was pretty hard to find. Sadly it doesn't say much more than there.

Thanks to all of you. I guess that if I want a total freedom while designing effects I'll have no other choices than hard limit on status recursion.

Comment: @Zibelas If you think you can detect loops automatically, [think again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). And even if you could detect infinite loops, that still leaves the game design question about what to do in that situation.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind is limiting an status to only resolve once per turn. Which would be by setting a flag as Romen suggested in comments.

---

One option to relax that it is to limit each status to resolve once *per cause*.

For example, with statuses:

- "On taking damage, heal 1"
- "On healing, take 1 damage"

When the entity takes damage from an attack, this happens:

- It takes damage from attack
- On taking damage, heal 1 (because of attack)
- On healing, take 1 damage (because status "On taking damage, heal 1")
- On taking damage, heal 1 (because status "On healing, take 1 damage")

The status "On healing, take 1 damage" won't trigger again, because it did already trigger from the "On taking damage, heal 1" status.

---

Another option to relax the rule is to say that you can have an status an integer number of times. In which case you could go from a flag to a counter.

This would also be useful if you stack statuses instead of allowing duplicates… Yet, consider making the status take the size of the stack as input to compute the effect.

---

I would still consider having a maximum of statuses resolved per turn, just to make sure a turn does not take too long to resolve (user experience).

---

By the way, when you have multiple statuses with their precondition satisfied, you need to pick which one to resolve. I would start with FIFO (a queue), so older status resolves first. However, might introduce priorities (a priority queue), so the oldest status of the higher priority resolves first.